# How can I inherit using TPT using EntityFramework from different Views?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, discriminator

Supposing I have two tables Meetings and Attendees.
My database looks like this.

```
// Table Meeting 
Id
Description
// other properties ...

// Attendee 
Id 
Name
MeetingId
// other properties ...
```

I have two views that are mapped to these tables. One is ViewMeetings with just the meeting data the other ViewMeetingAttendees joined with Attendees.

I want to use table per type(TPT), mapping each table to a view.

```
public abstract class MeetingBase 
{
    // Some properties here
}

public class ViewMeeting : MeetingBase
{ 
}

public class ViewMeetingAttendee : MeetingBase
{
      public String AttendeeName { get;set; }
}

// Configuration
moduleBuilder.Entity<ViewMeeting>().ToTable("ViewMeetings");
moduleBuilder.Entity<ViewMeetingAttendee>().ToTable("ViewMeetingAttendees");
// NOTE fixed the ViewMeeting error as stated in HansVG answer below.
```

Every time I try to run this code I get an error Invalid Column Name "Discriminator"

I understand that the entity framework is trying to resolve the types as a table per hierarchy(TPH). However, I still want to map the properties using inheritance without the inferred TPH. This is reasonable since all the columns are the same except for one. I have ten other columns and two views. Also I have a single meeting entity needing most of the same columns for CRUD operations.

Is there a way to keep the inheritance but lose the discriminator error? [NotMapped] is not an option since I am still pulling the data from the database. Also, I don't prefer to join the tables locally using LINQ since there are joined entities that don't need to be mapped otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You defined 'ViewMeeting' twice and didn't configure 'ViewMeetingAttendee'.
Your configuration should be:

```
moduleBuilder.Entity<ViewMeeting>().ToTable("ViewMeetings");
moduleBuilder.Entity<ViewMeetingAttendee>().ToTable("ViewMeetingAttendees");
```

Comment: That is a good catch and I will fix it in my post but I just made the typo in the post where I had map classes for the actual code which won't allow that  so unfortunately not the fix.